# Unable to set Textview over a listview

Tags: android

Im trying to create an adaptive layout containing a textview,listview and a button.Following is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/selectedComplianceList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="6dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/cont" />

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/cont"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
       <Button
           android:id="@+id/submit_area"
           style="@style/btn"
           android:layout_margin="2dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:text="Submit"
           android:padding="5dp"
           />
   </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="ComplianceNames"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/selectedComplianceList"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The textview has to be at the top of the listview and button should be at the bottom.

1. Textview is not visible at the top. How can I make it visible
2. Even though I have used divided height property, the listview items are not equally spaced enough. Moreover,if im setting the divider, the size of divider is high. How can I make it thin?

Comment: You can have a header and a footer to listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use **LinearLayout(Vertical)** its better option because you want three controls in vertical lines.
so try to do below code its very easy to understand and implements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="ComplianceNames"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/selectedComplianceList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/cont"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use     `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` in TextView , `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in LinearLayout and

```
 android:layout_above="@+id/cont"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" in ListView



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="ComplianceNames"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/selectedComplianceList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/cont"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cont"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit_area"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Submit" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="ComplianceNames"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/selectedComplianceList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_above="@+id/submit_area"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="6dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit_area"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="ComplianceNames"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/selectedComplianceList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/cont"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cont"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit_area"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Submit" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```